# "ObjectMessage usage is generally discouraged", what to use instead?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

The ActiveMQ docs [state](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html):

> Although ObjectMessage usage is generally discouraged, as it
>   introduces coupling of class paths between producers and consumers,
>   ActiveMQ supports them as part of the JMS specification

Having not had much experience with message busses, I have been approaching them as conceptually similar to SOAP web services, where you specify the service interface contract for consumers, who then construct equivalent class proxies.

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. Publishers in some way indicate the schema of the message
2. Subscribers in some way know the schema of the message

ObjectMessage solves this problem, although not in the nicest way given the noted classpath coupling.  As far as I can see the other message types provide minimal guidance to the consumer as to the expected message format (e.g. consumers would have to assume that a MapMessage contained certain keys with certain value types).

Is there another reasonable way to accomplish this, or is this not even something I should be pursuing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the idea is for publishers/subscribers to know about the schema. The first step is to definitely have a structure to the payload using JSON/ protobuf. (Not a big fan of XML personally). And then we pass the data as either TextMessage / BytesMessage.

While the idea is for publishers/subscribers to communicate the schema. Couple of ways to achieve this:

1. Subscriber knows about the schema via publishér's javadoc or sample invocations . (Sounds fine for simple use-cases)
2. Have a centralized config to publish both the publisher and for the subscriber to pick up from. This config could lie in a database/ application that serves out configurations. An effective implementation would ensure neither publisher/subscriber will break if there are modifications.

Advantages of this approach over the Object message approach:

1. No tight coupling of payload (i.e jar upgrades/attribute changes etc)
2. Significant performance improvement - Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/jmesnil/3187135) where a Java class with string and int takes 3.7x times more than directly storing int and string as bytes.